# How do I drop values from apply in R?

Tags: r, apply

```
list_of_means<-parApply(cl,mydataframe,2,function(x) mean(x))
```

Some of the columns in my dataframe only have NA's or copies of the same value (ie 1,1,1,1,1,etc.)

What do I need to add to the function in apply to skip the output for those columns? Or do I have to modify my dataframe first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition to filter on `all(is.na(x))`:

```
list_of_means<-parApply(cl,mydataframe,2,function(x) {
  if (! all(is.na(x))){ return(mean(x))  }})
```

If all elements are NAs, it will return nothing.

NB: if you have NAs you should consider using `na.rm` argument in `mean` function for more information please check `? mean`.

Comment: Is there also a way to filter out columns that are all zero's or all of one number?

Comment: You could use `data.table::uniqueN` or `length(unique(x))` to check how many unique values you have...

Comment: Thanks! This has been really helpful!